# Is it possible to apply :hover to this CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to use this style of CSS

```
nav ul li{
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

but I want to apply the hover.

I tried

```
nav ul li:hover{
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

and I also tried it with a space

```
nav ul li: hover{
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
```

Neither appeared to work.

Comment: You know, that there is no difference between your background-value? It's both rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1).

Comment: First of all, you don't need a space for pseudo classes. What background color are you using for the body? I see you are using white for your navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

It will work fine; you just didn't set a different color.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojvBKG

```css
nav ul li{
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
nav ul li:hover{
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Test list item</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```